# Eleventy site builder: Make JavaScript function available for Nunjucks templates

Tags: javascript, liquid, nunjucks, eleventy

How can I provide JavaScript functions for my Nunjucks templates when building websites with Eleventy?

Let's suppose I have a Nunjucks layout file `my_layout.njk` in the folder `_includes`:

```
<!doctype html>
{% set targetItem = findItemById(items, itemId) %}
<p>The value of the item with id {{ itemId }} is {{ targetItem.val }}.</p>
```

The called function `findItemById(items, id)` is defined in the config file `.eleventy.js` in the project's root folder. I am using the method `addJavaScriptFunction()` as described in Eleventy's documentation about [adding JS functions](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/languages/javascript/#javascript-template-functions).

```
module.exports = function(eleventyConfig) {
    eleventyConfig.addJavaScriptFunction("findItemById", function(items, id) {
        return items.find(item => item.id === id);
    });
};
```

The array of items to process is stored in the file `items.json` in the folder `_data`:

```json
[
    {
        "id": "a",
        "val": "foo"
    },
    {
        "id": "b",
        "val": "bar"
    }
]
```

Finally, I have a liquid template file `item_b.liquid` in the project's root folder to build a static html page with data from items array. When building the site, I know an item's id and need to get it's value.

```
---
layout: my_layout.njk
itemId: b
---
```

The desired output in the '_site' folder would a html file `item_b/index.html` with the content

```
<!doctype html>
<p>The value of item with id b is bar.</p>
```

However, Eleventy cannot find the function `findItemById`. When running `npx @11ty/eleventy` I get the error message:

```
[11ty] Problem writing Eleventy templates: (more in DEBUG output)
[11ty] 1. Having trouble writing to "_site/item_b/index.html" from "./item_b.liquid" (via EleventyTemplateError)
[11ty] 2. (./_includes/my_layout.njk) [Line 1, Column 32]
[11ty]   Error: Unable to call `findItemById`, which is undefined or falsey (via Template render error)
```

I am using Eleventy version 2.0.1 on Fedora 38 Linux.

Answer (score -1):

addJavaScriptFunction is not a thing in Eleventy as far as I know. But you can create a filter to accomplish what you want. Assuming that items is an array, you can create a filter and you would call it in Nunjucks like this:

{% set targetItem = items | findItemById(itemId) %}

See this page for more info:

https://www.11ty.dev/docs/filters/

Also, there's a ton of Eleventy help on their Discord server and there are more than 1,000 blog posts about a Eleventy on this site. And there is a section specifically on filters, here:

https://11tybundle.dev/categories/filters/

Comment: Hey Bob, thanks, as a supplement to my question: I am using the method addJavaScriptFunction() as described in the Eleventy Documentation about adding [JS functions](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/languages/javascript/#javascript-template-functions), should have mentioned that. I will check out the resources you have provided.

Comment: Thanks for enlightening me about the addJavascriptFunction. I could not find it when I searched the docs. It seems that you can only use that in templates that are js templates. Hope you can get it working with filters or some other technique.